# 'shared' is unavailable use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to add 1 library in to my code but after adding framework using pod install and converting the code to Swift 3, I am getting the above mentioned error here.

```
public override init() {
        super.init()
        size = UIApplication.shared.delegate!.window!!.bounds.size //Error here
    }
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34034271/swift-sharedapplication-is-unavailable-use-view-controller-based-solutions or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609776/uiapplication-sharedapplication-is-unavailable ?

Comment: It is not duplicate because that is for "sharedapplication()". I checked stackoverflow and then posted my question.

Comment: `sharedApplication` was renamed to `shared` in Swift 3, so it *could* be the same problem.

Comment: If it is named shared then why there is error. I just updated my cocoa pods and error remains. There is no solution given for Swift 3 on stack.

Comment: Tried both solutions before posting this question. "self.extensionContext?" does not exists in Swift 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want the main screen's bounds you can get them by using the following code.

```
let mainScreenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
```