# Accessing `shared` variable of `UIApplication` from inside `share extension` in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiapplication

I need to execute my host app from inside an extension. In `Objective-C` I've used this:

```
// Get "UIApplication" class name through ASCII Character codes.
NSString *className = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithBytes:(unsigned char []){0x55, 0x49, 0x41, 0x70, 0x70, 0x6C, 0x69, 0x63, 0x61, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6F, 0x6E} length:13] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
if (NSClassFromString(className))
{
    //  A different way to call [UIApplication sharedApplication]
    id object = [NSClassFromString(className) performSelector: @selector(sharedApplication)];
    //  These lines invoke selector with 3 arguments
    SEL selector = @selector(openURL:options:completionHandler:);
    id  (*method)(id, SEL, id, id, id) = (void *)[object methodForSelector: selector];
    method(object, selector, myURL, nil, nil);
    //  Close extension
    [self.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems: @[] completionHandler: nil];
}
```

But in `Swift` I have a couple of issues:

1. `UIApplication` does not have `sharedApplication` method anymore. Instead it has a class property `shared`. So I can not perform a selector to get shared instance. I've tried to bypass this by writing an extension

   extension UIApplication
   {
   class func shared() -> UIApplication
   {
   return UIApplication.shared
   }
   }

but I get an error `Function produces expected type 'UIApplication'; did you mean to call it with '()'?`. Adding these braces will give me an infinite loop.

2. Even if I get the instance somehow, I can't understand how to invoke `open` method.

   let selector = NSSelectorFromString("open(_:options:completionHandler:)")
   let method = object?.method(for: selector)
   method(destinationURL, String: Any, nil)

The last line gives me `Cannot call value of non-function type 'IMP'`. When pressing on the type in apple's documents, nothing happens. I can't find a description of `IMP` and how to work with it.

You might say: "just set `Require only app-extension-safe api` to `NO` in your extension's settings and call `UIApplication.shared` normally". To which I would reply that my builds get rejected by `iTunes Connect` with a message `Compliance with export requirements is required` or something along those lines (iTunes Connect is in Russian when my entire OS is in English).

So here are the questions:

1. Is there a way to get `UIApplication.shared` using ASCII codes in `Swift`?

BTW I get class name like so

```
let codes = [CUnsignedChar](arrayLiteral: 0x55, 0x49, 0x41, 0x70, 0x70, 0x6C, 0x69, 0x63, 0x61, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6F, 0x6E)
let className = String(data: Data(bytes: UnsafeRawPointer(codes), count: 13), encoding: String.Encoding.ascii) ?? ""
```

2. How do I invoke a method that has type `IMP`?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your extension works for me... Check your Swift version

Comment: @paper1111 If you are talking about `Objective-C` code: it is working. I have an issue with replication the same behaviour in `Swift`.

Comment: "Export compliance" is about confirming that your app complies to the export *laws* (such as software encryption). I wonder how that is related to your problem stated here.

Comment: @Igor I'm talking about Swift

Comment: @all,  I implemented shared extension in my app, In iOS 13, my share extension app can not open main app to receive shared file/image due to UIApplication.shared is unavailable now. Previous all version works fine. So, how could developer receive/import data from different sources ? Any workaround ?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you shouldn't try to access `sharedApplication` from your extension in the first place.

As per [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW2):

> **Some APIs Are Unavailable to App Extensions**
>
> Because of its focused role in the system, an app extension is ineligible to participate in certain activities. An app extension cannot:
>
> - Access a sharedApplication object, and so cannot use any of the methods on that object

So you may hack your way through it, but that will result in your application being rejected upon review.

However, to do what you're trying to do (open a URL) you don't need `sharedApplication` - you can simply do that using `NSExtensionContext`s [open(_:completionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsextensioncontext/1416791-open)

```
extensionContext.open(myUrl, completionHandler: myCompletionHandler)
```

Comment: The problem is that `extensionContext` can't open host app.

Answer (score 5):

Although `.shared` property is not available in extensions directly, you can access it via `#keyPath`:

`let application = UIApplication.value(forKeyPath: #keyPath(UIApplication.shared)) as! UIApplication`

Comment: I think that keyPath is like accessing to a private API, so Apple will decline your application during publishing procedure.

Comment: @AlessioCrestani, nope, keyPaths isn't like using private APIs.